# Immortality Injection Short Story?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia, immortality

I've been desperately trying to remember the name of this short story I read in high school, almost 10 years ago.
The premise was there was a "cure" for death, and a bunch of parents were giving it to their kids, but there was a mass suicide attempt by all the kids that got this vaccine, because they didn't want to live forever.
I thought it was something like the Cure for Death, but it's not coming up, and 90% of my search results are about Covid.
As a side note, I can't remember if I read this in my English or Spanish class.
Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but [*Cure for Death*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?321347) is the title of a 1961 novel by Victor Valentine. You can red a review on pp. 22-23 of [*Vector* 10](https://www.fanac.org/fanzines/Vector/Vector10.pdf#view=Fit). Thire is an old *Weird Tale* called "The Death Cure" but that's not it either.

Comment: Makes me think of Sharon Webb's Earthchild series (which had a couple of short stories in the series) - there's a cure of aging, that will only work on children.  Were the children in your story musically talented?

Comment: Have some matchs to 'Le grand Secret' (The immortals. Or how to spoil the reveal in the title) From René Barjavel(French), but also have more discrepencies, so probably not it.

Comment: I remember the same story and I associate it with Spanish class.

Answer (score 8):

**“Nosotros No” (“Not us”) by José Bernardo Adolph**

- There is a cure for death.
- You have to take it before 20 years old.
- The first boy at 15 kills himself.
- The story ends with the prediction that the injections will become compulsory and
  that the immortals would beg for an end.

Remembered from Spanish class and found by searching "Inyeccion de inmortalidad"

[Link to the text of the story in English.](https://franklin.dyer.me/file/NosotrosNo.pdf?msclkid=e628e94fb11c11eca8629422148c27f7)

Comment: I wonder if this is the same story where adults resent the kids, i recall some kid's dad actually attacks him. The treatment affects the appearance of one's skin.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been wracking my brain on this for ages-- I tried looking up inyeccion de immortalidad too, but nothing came up short story related.

Comment: @Chromien You're welcome.  You can click the check mark to accept this as the correct answer.